# total ram size linux sysinfo vs /proc/meminfo

Tags: c++, linux, memory, ram

```
 struct sysinfo sys_info;
 int32_t total_ram = 0;    
 if (sysinfo(&sys_info) != -1)
   total_ram = (sys_info.totalram * sys_info.mem_unit)/1024;
```

The value of total_ram from the above code is 3671864. But the /proc/meminfo shows a different value.

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
MemTotal:       16255004 kB
```

Why are they different? What is the correct way to get the physical RAM size in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to overflow. When numbers over 4 billion (such as 4GB+ RAM) are involved, make sure to use 64bit+ types:

```
 struct sysinfo sys_info;
 int32_t total_ram = 0;    
 if (sysinfo(&sys_info) != -1)
   total_ram = ((uint64_t) sys_info.totalram * sys_info.mem_unit)/1024;
```

Here's a self contained example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main() {
  struct sysinfo sys_info;
  int32_t before, after;
  if (sysinfo(&sys_info) == -1) return 1;

  before = (sys_info.totalram * sys_info.mem_unit)/1024;
  after = ((uint64_t)sys_info.totalram * sys_info.mem_unit)/1024;
  printf("32bit intermediate calculations gives %d\n", before);
  printf("64bit intermediate calculations gives %d\n", after);
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo -m32 -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic && ./foo
32bit intermediate calculations gives 2994988
64bit intermediate calculations gives 61715244
```